# RBG values to colour name Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I was looking to convert given RGB values to the actual colour name in Python or atleast the close match of the colour.

Given the values, 
[50.2862498  72.08996663 70.66173433] I want to be able to distinguish these values from [185.89894822 186.47802004 185.94613642] as a shade of green.

Reason I need to do that is to remove shades of green from an image.

Comment: check this repo https://github.com/ayushoriginal/Optimized-RGB-To-ColorName

Comment: Thank you! Is there a simpler way to remove shades of green from an image?

Comment: Removing shades of green and repacing it with.?

Comment: White. Basically removing vegetation from an image.

Comment: I separated the colours using Kmeans and I am unable to proceed removing a certain colour.

Comment: I think this will help http://answers.opencv.org/question/97416/replace-a-range-of-colors-with-a-specific-color-in-python/

Comment: Use the HSV or HSL colorspace, in which hue is on a colorwheel and you can select anything in a range of hues regardless of their brightness/darkness.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `webcolors` python package here: https://pypi.org/project/webcolors/1.3/. It looks like the `rgb_to_name(rgb_triplet, spec='css3')` function does exactly what you want.

From the documentation,

> Convert a 3-tuple of integers, suitable for use in an rgb() color triplet, to its corresponding normalized color name, if any such name exists.
>   The optional keyword argument spec determines which specification’s list of color names will be used; valid values are html4, css2, css21 and css3, and the default is css3.
>   If there is no matching name, ValueError is raised.

Example provided:

```
>>> rgb_to_name((0, 0, 0))
'black'
```

Comment: color names in `webcolors` is limited I think

Comment: the package is very limited.